# MATLAB Using a single figure frame for chasePlot used inside a loop

Tags: matlab, plot, while-loop, matlab-figure, infinite-loop

I have a while loop inside of which I have to use a plot and a chasePlot function.

The problem is, it comes up with a new window figure each time the loop runs. I somehow want a single frame which can be updated rather than each time making a new window and figure for it.

Anybody knows how to prevent a new figure in each loop so that one figure is there and that keeps on updating.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'figure' before the 'plot' command and the code will keep overwriting every time on the same figure. You can also use the 'drawnow limitrate' command for better visualization. See an example below:

```
    clc; close all; clear all; 

    x = 0 :100 :1e5;

    y = zeros(size(x));

    for n = 1:numel(x)

        y(n) = sin(x(n));

        plot(x(1:n), y(1:n));

        drawnow limitrate;

    end
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't think this is problem  
Here is the code, because of WHILE(1) I get new plot window each time  
I just want 1 plot window and I want it updated rather than a new plot each time. How to do it?  
`while (1)  
s = drivingScenario;  
road(s, [-100 -100;100 100],50);  
passingCar = actor(s);  
waypoints = [Dist1 Dist3
              Dist2 Dist4]';  
velocities = [10];  
while advance(s)  
pause(0.1);  
path(passingCar, waypoints,velocities);
chasePlot(passingCar,'Waypoints','on','Centerline','on')
plot(s,'Waypoints','on','Centerline','on');  
end
end`

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to put line breaks.  
Somehow double space doesn't work.

Comment: It is not clear that how multiple figure windows can be generated when you are not defining the 'figure'. MATLAB is supposed to overwrite on the same figure every time. Even with the 'while' loop the things remain same. Here is the same example with the 'while' loop:  clc; close all; clear all; 

    x = 0 :100 :1e5;

    y = zeros(size(x));
    
    n = 1;

    while (n <= numel(x))

        y(n) = sin(x(n));

        plot(x(1:n), y(1:n));

        drawnow limitrate;
        
        n = n + 1;

    end

Comment: Moreover, the condition 'while (1)' in your code will always be true and the code will never come out of the loop. It will keep running always.

Comment: 1. But I have a while (1) so thats why a new figure is made each time.  
I used **hAxes = axes** inside while loop and then used its handle, so then it just stayed in one figure.  
Meanwhile if you put a while(1) in front of your code so it will also generate a new figure each time!  
2. Yes I need it to run continuously as I wanna fetch data continuously from sensor in real time.